# Почему сбрасывается описание анонс при выгрузке из 1С?

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

Есть сайт на 1с-битрикс редакция бизнес. Сделана стандартная интеграция с 1С. После выгрузки всех товаров, меняю описание анонса. После повторной выгрузке, сбрасывается описание анонса на название товара. В чем может быть дело? Куда следует обратить внимание?

Comment: "меняю описание анонса" - на сайте или в 1с ? Нужно смотреть что приходит из 1с, то и записывается

Comment: можно повесить событие на изменение элемента, и записывать например в файлик как меняется элемент, так логировать что происходит

Comment: Меняю на сайте описание анонса